# How to take specific elements from the output of command and then display in a table format?

Tags: bash, macos, awk, terminal

I tend to use the macos command `diskutil info -all` frequently and it has a lot more information than I usually want, and it displays it in a sort of list type format and with 19 hard drives attached it means a lot of scrolling around.  I am trying to extract only four bits of information from the output of `diskutil info -all` and then format it into a table of four columns.

I am using grep to the exact info I want with:

`diskutil info -all | grep -e "Device Identifier:" -e "Device Node:" -e "Volume Name:" -e "Volume UUID:"`

and that results in out such as this:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Identifier:        disk1s1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s1
   Volume Name:              EFI
   Device Identifier:        disk1s2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s2
   Volume Name:              Old-Timemachine-Lion
   Volume UUID:              D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
   Device Identifier:        disk1s3
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s3
   Volume Name:              Backup-Lion
   Volume UUID:              8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
   Device Identifier:        disk1s4
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1s4
   Volume Name:              Old-Timemachine-Garnet
   Volume UUID:              DECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

I want to strip out the first column and then divide the second into four columns, one column for each parameter.  The above snippet of output would look like:

```
   disk0      /dev/disk0        Not applicable (no file system)
   disk1      /dev/disk1        Not applicable (no file system)
   disk1s1    /dev/disk1s1      EFI
   disk1s2    /dev/disk1s2      Old-Timemachine-Lion                D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
   disk1s3    /dev/disk1s3      Backup-Lion                         8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
   disk1s4    /dev/disk1s4      Old-Timemachine-Garnet              ECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

I found I can use cut to get rid of the first column and thought I should be able to use printf and command substitution to format into columns.  Something like:

```
printf "%14s    %14s    %14s    %14s\n" "$(diskutil info -all | grep -e "Device Identifier:" -e "Device Node:" -e "Volume Name:" -e "Volume UUID:" | cut -c 30-70)"
```

It works to get rid of the first column but doesn't format, it is like the printf isn't working.  The output looks like:

```
disk0
/dev/disk0
Not applicable (no file system)
disk1
/dev/disk1
Not applicable (no file system)
disk1s1
/dev/disk1s1
EFI
disk1s2
/dev/disk1s2
Old-Timemachine-Lion
D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
disk1s3
/dev/disk1s3
Backup-Lion
8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
disk1s4
/dev/disk1s4
Old-Timemachine-Garnet
DECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

I am not strong with shell scripting so I doubt my approach is the best one but what am missing and/or doing wrong here?  I would like to learn.

Comment: In the `diskutils` results, are there space before the start of each line? Or it something that got introduced while formating in SO?

Comment: @sjsam - `diskutil` puts three spaces at the beginning of each line, so a `sub(/^ */,"")` in awk would provide sufficient trim.

Comment: @sjsam, ghoti is correct.  There are three spaces inserted by diskutil at the start of each line.  I don't particularly care about them.  Maybe having a space or two or three to move the results away from the edge is prettier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command after your `diskutil info -all | grep -e "Device Identifier:" -e "Device Node:" -e "Volume Name:" -e "Volume UUID:"`

```
$ diskutil info -all | grep -e "Device Identifier:" -e "Device Node:" -e "Volume Name:" -e "Volume UUID:" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":";}/Device Identifier/{print ""}{printf $2}END{printf "\n"};' | sed -e 's/ \{3,\}/@/g;' | column -s'@' -t
disk0    /dev/disk0    Not applicable (no file system)
disk1    /dev/disk1    Not applicable (no file system)
disk1s1  /dev/disk1s1  EFI
disk1s2  /dev/disk1s2  Old-Timemachine-Lion             D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
disk1s3  /dev/disk1s3  Backup-Lion                      8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
disk1s4  /dev/disk1s4  Old-Timemachine-Garnet           DECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

where

- `BEGIN{FS=":";}` defines the field separator for awk at `:`
- `/Device Identifier/{print ""}` prints an EOL each time you reach a new Device Identifier
- `{printf $2}` will make the translate your vertical disk properties  horizontally
- `END{printf "\n"}` prints a last EOL char
- `sed -e 's/ \{3,\}/@/g;| column -s'@ -t` you pipe it to sed and column to reshape it properly and you have the following output:

[image]

Comment: Have you noticed the tabs that got introduced here? For instance `Not                     applicable` ?

Comment: Thank you for the pick! It's time to take a break and have lunch ;-) (I have edited the post to correct that)

Comment: Thank you!   It seems everyone has suggested awk, and no-one has offered a reason why what I was doing didn't work right with printf.  I am kind of bummed about that.  But, even though the solutions were all variations with awk, you are the only one who tendered an explanation for what the code you have added to my original command attempt does.  I appreciate this immensely as without the explanation the code solves the task but doesn't teach me how it works very well as I don't know sed or awk yet. Thank you!

Comment: The reason your printf solution isn't working is that `printf` is "naive" about reading its inputs. each "word" of input matched to each format specifier in sequence. Printf can't know that `Not applicable (no file system)` (for instance) is meant to go to just one of the `%14s    ` format specifiers, `Not applicable...` gets "split" with each word going to each `%14s    ` in turn. I tried to trick it with tab separated output with an `IFS="\t"` and quoting it like `"Not applicable (no file system)"` but that didn't work. IHTH

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '
/Device Identifier/{
  if(val){
    print val};
  val=$NF
}
/Device Node:/{
  val=val OFS $NF
}
/Volume Name:/{
  sub(/Volume Name:* +/,"");
  val=val OFS $0
}
/Volume UUID:/{
  sub(/Volume UUID:* +/,"");
  val=val OFS $0
}
END{
  if(val){
    print val}
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
disk0 /dev/disk0    Not applicable (no file system)
disk1 /dev/disk1    Not applicable (no file system)
disk1s1 /dev/disk1s1    EFI
disk1s2 /dev/disk1s2    Old-Timemachine-Lion    D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
disk1s3 /dev/disk1s3    Backup-Lion    8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
disk1s4 /dev/disk1s4    Old-Timemachine-Garnet    DECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  Both you and @James did it all in awk.  I really do need to learn awk.  Detail on what you were doing would really have been helpful as all this awk everyone has used is quite obscure to me at this point.

Comment: @CKnight, glad that it helped you. Don't worry once you started learning it will be fine. We all are learning day by day here, cheers :)

Comment: Hi, I am looking again at your code in context of what @James had said in a comment about the left being the pattern and the right being the awk code to do something.  I am surmising that the "right" is actually what is in the curly brackets.  But in your code at the bottom you say "Input_file".  What exactly is this?  Is this the piped in results from diskutil ?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use awk. This is exactly the kind of thing it as made for. It's a funky tool, but once you learn it it's useful for all manner of translation/tabulation tasks.

Here's a quick stab at your problem:

```
#!/bin/awk

/Device Identifier:/ { device=$3 }
/Device Node:/ { node=$3 }
/Volume Name:/ { split($0,parts,/:/); part2=parts[2]; sub(/^[ \t]*/,"",part2); name=part2 }
/Volume UUID:/ { uuid=$3 }
/^\*+/ { printf("%-10s %-16s %-40s %s\n",device,node,name,uuid) }
```

Put that in a file then run `diskutil info -all | awk -f ~/Desktop/that_file.awk`

This is just the tip of the iceberg. awk can make decisions, do math, etc. It's a poor man's perl, but I find my head doesn't explode when I use it. ;)

Comment: Oh, and @ravindersingh13 parsed the volume name much better than I did.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  Both you and @Ravindersingh13 did it all in awk.  I really do need to learn awk as the solutions seems simpler?  Detail on what you were doing would really have been helpful.

Comment: Hard to describe awk in 500 characters, but here goes: awk programs are a sequence of pattern/code pairs. Each pattern (on the left) is matched again each input line. If the line matches pattern, the statements on the right get executed. It uses a shell-like language with variable, functions, conditions, loops, etc.

Comment: My program is pretty typical. Each pattern is looking for something in the output. A line that matches that pattern executes the code on the right, which simply plucks out the value it was looking for and stores it in a variable. ($0 is the whole input line, $1 is the first whitespace delimited field, $2 is the second field, and so on.) Conveniently, disktuil spits out a line of '*****' after each record, so I use that pattern to dump the last set of values. Far from perfect, but simple and probably useful.

Comment: I googled and found an [awk tutorial] (http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) that I am going to read this weekend.  For quick fix, I turned what @Allan offered into an alias (after a bit of escaping).   I am thinking to turn what I've seen in all these helpful answers to my questions into a bash function with table headers and maybe an optional arugument to reduce output further and only get the lines that have a UUID in them and learn a little awk while doing it.  :-)  Thank you so much for taking the time to come back and elaborate on your code.  It really is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I used `sed` to do a bit of preprocessing before passing the input to `awk`. Also I have replaced the spaces in each fields with underscores(hope that is not a problem) to give more consistent results with `column -t`

```
diskutil info -all |
grep -e "Device Identifier:" -e "Device Node:" -e "Volume Name:" -e "Volume UUID:" |
sed -E 's/^[[:blank:]]*(Device Identifier:.*)$/\n\1/;
s/[[:blank:]]+/ /g;
s/^[[:blank:]]+//;s/: /:/' |
awk -v RS="" -v FS=":" '{
for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2){
gsub(/ /,"_",$i);printf "%s ",$i
}
printf "\n"
}' | column -t
```

**Output**

```
disk0    /dev/disk0    Not_applicable_(no_file_system)
disk1    /dev/disk1    Not_applicable_(no_file_system)
disk1s1  /dev/disk1s1  EFI
disk1s2  /dev/disk1s2  Old-Timemachine-Lion             D04D1888-ABD9-3480-9692-60ECA458C372
disk1s3  /dev/disk1s3  Backup-Lion                      8C737824-F790-324B-AC4C-6F398D6CE947
disk1s4  /dev/disk1s4  Old-Timemachine-Garnet           DECBEC2C-ADFD-397E-88B6-B9CC962E00E4
```

Comment: Thank you for you help with this.  I don't know sed or awk so I don't really follow what is going on in your code which is unfortunate. I do need to learn these obviously powerful tools. The addition of the underscores don't bother me really but at the same time I don't understand why they helped.

Comment: @CKnight `column -t` tab-separates the fields based on space deimiter. Consider what would happen if a single field has spaces in it. That is where the underscores helped. Good that you're planning to add `sed` and `awk` in your repertoire. They are great tools indeed. `:-)`

Comment: Thank you again.  Yep, this weekend is planned for learning some awk. :-)  I have not googled up a tutorial on sed yet, but it is on my list to do.